# Роутинг в RoR на статическую страницу

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как настроить routes.rb так что бы все get запросы направлялись на статический файл index.html который находится в папке public?

Comment: Ы. А зачем тогда вообще Rails? :)

Comment: Все для API....

Comment: Так всё-таки не все?

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать SPA на React и прикрутить это дело к Rails. Люблю Rails за его простоту и понятный код, а в 5-ой версии а теперь c легкостью можно only API приложения делать. Так что экспериментирую =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Роутов для статических файлов, на сколько я знаю, не бывает.
Рельсы сначала проверяют наличие урла в роутах, если нет - пытаются отдать статику.
Соответственно, если убрать из `routes.rb` все роуты, то приложение будет будет отвечать на `/` и `index.html` как раз тем самым статичным файлом.
А вот сделать так, чтобы он возвращался в ответ на ВСЕ get-запросы средствами Rails проблемматично. Да и не нужно это для SPA. Обыно, для этого используется реально один путь, у которого могут быть разные аргументы/якоря/прочее. Вот пример от гугла: `https://www.google.ru/#q=SPA`.

Answer (score 0):

**Маршруты могут направить только в контроллер или в 404.** Всё.

Но можно отдавать статические файлы из контроллера. Поэтому самый "лобовой" путь это сделать контроллер-"пустышку" с одним методом, состоящим из вызова `send_file`.

При должной настройке при этом можно воспользоваться особенностями реализации обратного прокси, чтобы Rails выдал путь к отдаваемому файлу проксе, а уже прокся выдала файл (она обычно эффективнее может это делать). На `nginx` это делается через заголовок `X-Accel-Redirect`. Соответственно, все роуты (после API, чем ниже тем ниже приоритет), [направить туда при помощи `match`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match). **Но это плохой путь**, хотя отдельные его части могут понадобиться где-то ещё.

---

**Лучше не доводить запрос до сервера приложения и системы маршрутов вообще**, а выбрать для запросов к API некий префикс/поддомен, то же для статики, а на остальное отдавать `index.html`. А уж как это сделать, ищите по названию вашего прокси (например, `nginx`) документацию или статьи.